# rdio and spotify like now-playing bar in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

How would one create a now-playing like bar that can be swiped up from the bottom and swiped away from the top, that would always overlap some views but not all views - something like a z-index stacking with swipeable gestures on views?

It should work with something like [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)

On iOs :-)

Screenshot of functionality here:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for adding the image, i wasn't allowed because I am a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding a subview to your UIViewcontroller (or JASidePanels, as it may be) and bringing it to the front. Something like:

```
BottomBarView *bottomBar = [[BottomBarView alloc] init];
[self addSubview:bottomBar];
[self bringSubviewToFront:bottomBar];
```

Note that this would be from your UIViewController, and not from AppDelegate.

Another option is to add the subview using a XIB or Storyboard and use Interface Builder to make sure that the view is at the right z-index.

To make it swipeable, you just have to listen for the right gestures, and to hide it, use `bringSubviewToFront` on some other view.